# Python Quantlib construct YTM (not zero) curve

Tags: finance, quantitative-finance, quantlib

I have non-par yields and maturities.

Is there a way to construct a government bond YTM curve using quantlib and YTM of not spot/zero yields, but coupon paying bonds?
I am looking at the documentation for Term Structures and Curves; but there is nothing about YTM curve

https://quantlibjl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/term_structures.html

I want to construct the said YTM curve, and spot rate curve using the same data, to compare the results?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by a YTM curve: what do you do with 2 bonds with the same maturity but different coupons: they will have different yields? The typical process is to create FixedRateBondHelpers which have all the bond details (coupon, maturity, frequency, conventions, settle lag etc), as you would for a price <-> yield calculation. You can then pass these to either a bootstrap or a spline method to create a curve of discount factors, from which you can back out a par yield for a given maturity.